# Build FAILED : Unknown host 'repo.maven.apache.org'

Tags: android, maven, gradle, proxy

Please, help me. I get this error when i build my android Project.

> Unknown host 'repo.maven.apache.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy
> settings in Gradle.

This is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is my app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication5"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And this is a gradle.properties in C:/users/%username%/.gradle:

```
## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
#Tue May 10 17:19:59 GMT 2022
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
```

This is HTTP Proxy in [Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N81zk.png).
Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is a long shot but I was facing this same error because I did not had a run/debug configuration.

If it is your case you will see 'No configuration' instead of what I show you on the following image:

[image: run/debug configuration]

I solved it adding a default android app configuration template:

[image: Add new run configuration]

Answer (score 0):

You might have provided the wrong Gradle JDK path. Try changing it, worked for me